# How to allow `.` in my regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this code to prevent entering special chars

```
String.prototype.isText = function () {return /^[\w\s&'%]*$/.test(this)}
```

But i want it to allow entering dots in the string.

How can i change it to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add a dot:

```
String.prototype.isText = function () {return /^[\w\s&'%.]*$/.test(this)}
```

Comment: The . usually means "match everything"...

Comment: '.' would be any character except new line.  You have to escape it with a '\'

Comment: @kchau: Not inside square brackets it doesn't :)

Comment: @josh.trow Niceone. Then this is the best answer.

Comment: @josh.trow, Did a little research and you're right. However, it works either way (escaped or not). Still, +1 for you.

Answer (score 8):

```
String.prototype.isText = function () {return /^[\.\w\s&'%]*$/.test(this)}
```

Comment: The dot should not be escaped as it has no special meaning in the literal group.

Comment: The dot is a reserved character and must be escaped or it allows everything...

Comment: @ShaneBlake that is not true when it's used inside square brackets - in that context, it is **not** reserved.

Comment: @Shane: The dot has *definitely* not to be escaped in a character class.

Comment: That, my friends, is pretty jacked up...  Just tested and the brackets do change the meaning of '.'  I would still recommend using the escape since it works and it avoids this confusion, but to each his/her/it's own...

Comment: @ShaneBlake: I would dis-recommend it for the exact same reason (i.e., to avoid confusion). It obscures how regular expressions work by adding meaningless voodoo "just in case". There is no such thing as "preventive character escaping" - either you're sure or you're not. I'd rather be sure - if that means I must know the rule behind it: fine.

Comment: @Tomalak:  Like I said, to each their own...  :)

Comment: I would do it like this as well. Besides personal preference, it makes the code more readable.